# How can I get my javascript collision simulation more efficient?

Tags: javascript, performance, collision-detection, complexity-theory

I'm trying to improve my code for a collision simulation.
Let's take 1000 particles collision for example, all with the same radius for now.

This code runs about 1 million times:

```
for (i = 0; i<particles.length; i++){
   for (j = 0; j<particles.length; j++){
      if (particles[i] === particles[j]) continue;
      if (distanceOf(particle[i], particle[j] < radius*2)) {
         Collide(particles[i], particles[j]);
         }
    }
 }
```

Not very efficient.
Now, this code runs about 500,000 times:

```
for (i = 0; i<particles.length; i++){
   for (j = i + 1; j<particles.length; j++){
      if (particles[i] === particles[j]) continue;
      if (distanceOf(particle[i], particle[j] < radius*2)) {
         Collide(particles[i], particles[j]);
         }
    }
 }
```

Much better but still not efficient.
Next, is a code which should dramatically improve the efficiency by reducing the number of checks to only 4000 by checking each particle only with it's neighbors. I divided the screen into 16*16 sectors so each sector in every given moment has about 1000/256=4 particles, so each particle has only 4 checks(minus itself, iknow) so we get 4000 checks, which should work 125x faster than the last 500,000 checks code. 
The code is something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i<particles.length; i++){
   let cellNumber = particles[i].cell; //each particle updates a "cell" variable with it's own current cell number by calculating it from it's position.
   for (j = 0; j<sector[cellNumber].length; j++){ //sector[] is an array of 256 cells, each one is an array of the indexes of the particles in it.
      if (particles[i] === particles[sector[cellNumber][j]]) continue;
      if (distanceOf(particle[i], particles[sector[cellNumber][j]] < radius*2)) {
         Collide(particles[i], particles[sector[cellNumber][j]]);
         }
    }
 }
```

Should it be working 125x faster or is there other complexity issues that will limit it, and if so by what factor? If it's "only" 50 times faster I'm still happy.

Thanks

Comment: Is it an issue that particles on the edge of these sectors could be colliding with each other? If yes, then you cannot separate like this.

Comment: I am not the type to be difficult about typos, but I think your title refers to javascript and not jacascript?

Comment: Yes I know i need to make another grid of 256 cells in an offset to the first grid in order to resolve border issues. That's not my question though. i only want to know if there are complexity issues in this code that seriously hinders the efficiency of x125 times faster. For example: in this solution i need to have an array of 256 arrays, that should contain the indexes of my 1000 particles and I'm constantly checking against and updating this array. What impact does this have of the efficiency and consequently the speed of my program?

Comment: @Alafandy You'll be trading more memory for those saved calculations cycles, and you will need to account for time taken to distribute the particles, but other than that it looks sound

Comment: Why don't you implement it and do some benchmarks? The exact factor of improvement is heavily dependent on implementation, language and platform specifics.